# Is there any peace of DMA code?

Tags: pi-2

I've been stuck with same problem for a week, I cannot seem to get an idea on how dma works, maybe somebody can give me some working peace of code for DMA channels?

P.S. I don't want to show my code, because I'm just a beginner, I don't want to look like stupid :)

Thanks guys

Comment: https://github.com/Wallacoloo/Raspberry-Pi-DMA-Example first hit on google?

Comment: Showing code doesn't make you look stupid. We all were noobs once and that is how you learn. I have been working in IT for mpre than 2 decades and still learn new things every day.

Comment: In fact it is the contrary, *not* showing code *does* look stupid, and *asking for code instead* is a flat out [faux pas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106147/how-to-correctly-flag-or-vote-to-close-the-please-give-me-the-code-question).  No one cares how talented (or not) you are. If you want people to write code for you, use a freelance site.   If you want help with code you are working on, include it.   Someone might then fire back an example of their own if they feel it is appropriate.

Comment: BTW, one thing that's okay is to ask for an explanation of an example you've found (e.g. from one of joan's links).  Just make sure to cut n' paste the relevant section (meaning, it can't be an entire library, etc.) and ask specifically things like, "What is the purpose of the if/else clause here?" or "What is does that address refer to?", etc.

Comment: Thanks for explanation goldilocks :) Im fairly new to this forum. I asked for some code to see how other people implement it, and learn for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DMA on the Pi is simple to define, not quite so easy to implement.

At its simplest you program the hardware with a from address, a to address, and a number of bytes and say go.  It's the equivalent of [memcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html).

You can chain requests together, so one request can point to another, so you can start a whole sequence of copies.  That's just like many calls to memcpy.

You can point the last DMA entry back to the first so the whole sequence repeats.  That's just like many calls to memcpy with a loop back to the first.

On the Pi there are 16 different DMA channels which each operate independently.  Most are now reserved for system use.

From a kernel module you should be using the supplied kernel DMA functions.

From userland you will have to write your own functions (DMA wasn't really meant to be callable from userland).

If you want to try to understand the gory details you could have a look at my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) which was the first userland DMA implementation.

For a somewhat simpler example look at the userland version of [servoblaster](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster).